# How to send a get request and retrieve response data in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a REST Api and a groovy script from which in want to send a get request to my api and retrieve the response in an object.

the api returns a list of values like this :

```
[
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200
]
```

i want to send a GET request and retrieve this response in a variable in the most efficient and simple way

Answer (score 0):

You could do somehting like this:

import wslite.rest.RESTClient

```
class App {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        RESTClient client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:8080/")
        def path = "/demo"
        def response = client.get(path: path)
        List listOfNumbers = response.json
        println listOfNumbers
    }
}
```

That `RESTClient` is provided by `groovy-wslite`.  In Gradle you could express that dependency with something like this:

```
implementation 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.3'
```

Alternatively you could use a standalone script like this:

```
@Grab("com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.3")
import wslite.rest.RESTClient

RESTClient client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:8080/")
def path = "/demo"
def response = client.get(path: path)
List listOfNumbers = response.json
println listOfNumbers
```

Comment: I'm running a groovy script through a JAVA spring boot app so when i use the 'import wslite.rest.RESTClient' it shows an error saying cannot resolve symbol wslite

Comment: That is because you don't have `groovy-wslite` on your classpath. The `RESTClient` class is in the `groovy-wslite` `.jar` file.

Comment: is there an alternate way of achieving what I want without having to import the wslite?

Comment: "is there an alternate way of achieving what I want without having to import the wslite?" - Yes.  You could write your own HTTP client or you could use a different library.  Which would you prefer to see an example of?

Comment: If you would like to see a different solution, it might be good to adjust your question "i want to send a GET request and retrieve this response in a variable in the most efficient and simple way" to include "without using wslite".  That will yield different solutions if you specifically want to avoid `wslite`.