# How to send a request body in a HTTP POST request in groovy

Tags: http, groovy

So I'm running a spring boot application and I want to execute a POST request in a seperate groovy script.
my groovy script looks something like this :

```
var values = [1203,1138,1086,1557,1345,1557,1557,1557,1557,1557,1557,1557]
URL url = new URL("mycustomurl")
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
con.setRequestMethod("POST")
```

I want to put the values array in request body and send it in a POST request, how do I achieve that?
(preferably no external libraries involved)

Comment: people answering your questions and you have not marked any of those as "answered". do you mind to review your previous questions and upvote answers - so, you'll have more chances to get answers for your new questions...

Comment: they didn't really give me a working solution. Those answers didn't work for me

Comment: I am not going to paste Baeldung's content into an answer but he has provided good info on this at https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post.

Comment: "they didn't really give me a working solution." - The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924724/how-to-send-a-get-request-and-retrieve-response-data-in-groovy appears to work.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I really appreciate you helping me but the solution you provided didn't work for me as I encountered several problems with the wslite library. After rigorous search and with the help of Baeldung's content I finally managed to solve it on my own though.

Comment: "the solution you provided didn't work for me as I encountered several problems with the wslite library" - I am sorry that you had problems.  For the requirements expressed in the question I think it provides everything required.  I am glad that you got it worked out.

Comment: Use the `HttpBuilder`